# Formatos de table?

Tags: html

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer uma table contendo um "texto" no meio das linhas dela!

Segue um exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Seria isso que você procura? http://jsfiddle.net/MeeW2/

O HTML ficará assim:

```
<div>
    <h1><span>Div title</span></h1>
</div>
```

E o CSS, assim:

```
div{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

div h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -10px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

div h1 span{
    background-color: white;
}
```

Originalmente postado aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868267/div-title-on-div-border-how-to

Comment: Seria isso mesmo @FredDutra!

Comment: Funciona, e é interessante a forma como se resolveu. Porém observei que se, por exemplo, o tamanho da fonte for um pouquinho maior, ele poderá sobrepor outros elementos da página isso pelo uso do `margin` a negativo, dando ao texto uma espécie de posição absoluta. Acredito que depois o OP irá aprimorar neh... :)

Comment: Have my +1 good sir.

Comment: Sim, o OP deverá alterar para as necessidades dele. Quanto a essa questão da fonte, podemos fazer tanto alteração no próprio CSS como também podemos usar `media_query`, *JQuery*, ou um *Compass* para fazer versões diferentes ;)

Answer (score 3):

Usa um [`fieldset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset). A tag `fieldset` tem que ter necessariamente uma tag filha `legend`, que é o texto dele. Fica exatamente como você quer, essa tag foi criada pra isso.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Texto</legend>
    foo
</fieldset>
```

Exemplo no [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/q5zfqf5f/4/). Editei o exemplo pra legenda ficar mais pro centro.

Agora é só deixar a borda como você quiser e ser feliz. Você também pode reposicionar o legend usando margens e padding.

Comment: não creio que dessa forma ficará tal como a imagem descreve. Talvez adicionado um estilo(`css`) poderia chegar lá.

Comment: @Cold errei a tag com o texto. Acabo de corrigir.

Comment: Mas ainda assim, não sei se a legenda ficaria no centro, tal como na imagem. Era esta a minha questão.

Comment: @Cold olha meu fiddle ;)

Comment: @Renan desconheço dessa tag. Qual seria a compatibilidade dela com os browsers mais antigos, sei que no HTML5 ela rodaria tranquilamente, mas me pergunto quanto ao IE (antigo) e as versões MOBILE dos respectivos.

Comment: Sim, era mesmo aquela porção `CSS` que estava reclamando @Renan :P. Agora, será que 50% no `margin-left` coloca o texto no centro?Tentei escrever um texto maior e fica meio estranho. Recomendo o `text-align`.

Comment: @FredDutra É compatível com IE9. Acredito que com IE8. Todos os demais navegadores suportam, inclusive mobile (até onde sei). Esse campo era uma recomendação no HTML 4, e já faz parte do HTML 5. Olha a MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @FredDutra, quanto a compatibilidade veja:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp. Quanto a antiguidade e versões mobile, hum, terei de pesquisar mais.

Comment: @Cold vou deixar o CSS a cargo do OP, mas você tem razão. Margin 50% não centraliza.

Comment: Na paz @Renan. Pergunto porque no mundo web de hoje nós temos que nos preocupar com coisas mínimas. Só uma correção, se você souber o tamanho da sua div/texto, você poderá centralizar fazendo `left: 50%; margin:-valor da div`. Agora não me lembro se é margin-left ou margin-right :/

Comment: Acho que é margin: auto ou coisa do tipo. Se alguém souber, fique a vontade pra editar o Fiddle.